# How to download data from Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to retrieve some data from a Firebase database. I've been able to do it fine in the past, but there's something wrong with my GetValueAsync() code below. When debugging it gets stuck at the "await reference.Database" line, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When running without debugging, none of the information is ever retrieved.

I'm uncertain if the problem is with the path, or the await/async function. Debugging shows that loggedUserId is storing the value before referencing it in the next line, but the rest of the function never completes or faults. The application compiles but I'm never able to capture any info from the snapshot.

The format of my database is "users" -> 78cVqzA8qNTNigsao3VvdnM0Qol2 (Which is correct) -> (several data pairs such as level : 1, lives : 3, etc)

```
public static async void GetUserData()
{
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
    app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://narwhaltrivia.firebaseio.com/");
    if (app.Options.DatabaseUrl != null) app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(app.Options.DatabaseUrl);

    DatabaseReference reference = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    loggedUserId = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId;

    await reference.Database.GetReference("users").Child(loggedUserId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error retrieving user data");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot userSnapshot = task.Result;
            loggedEmail = userSnapshot.Child("email").GetRawJsonValue();
            loggedCurrentScore = userSnapshot.Child("currentScore").GetRawJsonValue();
            loggedLevel = userSnapshot.Child("level").GetRawJsonValue();
            loggedLives = userSnapshot.Child("lives").GetRawJsonValue();
            loggedRound = userSnapshot.Child("round").GetRawJsonValue();
            loggedTotalScore = userSnapshot.Child("totalScore").GetRawJsonValue();
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try without the async/await

Comment: Thank you but there was no change, it still never returns any value after GetValueAsync(). I also tried using a wait function thinking it could be taking awhile to download from the database, and this was the result from debugging.

getTask Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot, Firebase.Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Comment: If you removed it where is it getting the task request from?